# Jquery form validator with npm

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm

I Just started learning to use npm. I managed to install it from nodejs. I also install [jquery-form-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-form-validator) package on my project directory. My question is, **how to use it?**

Do I have to call it from the project directory like the normal procedure. eg, on my `registration.php`, I will use

```
<script src="js/form-validator/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
```

or I need to make some settings on the `package.json` file and create a new file to call it. Like on the npm [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally).